# Python - Get value from C++ pointer in DLL

Tags: python, c++, pointers, dll

I have an C++ method below compiled in DLL

```
int Method( int Error, char *pMessage, int Position);
```

while Error and Position is as input and *pMessage is for output

In Python I am using simple:

```
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("library")
mydll.Method(50,?,20)
```

For methods without pointers is everything fine. But how can i get values from C++ pointers in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `create_string_buffer`. What I miss in the C++ function is the size of the string, so I'll assume it is constant (although it might be a bad practice):

```
from ctypes import create_string_buffer, cdll

N_OF_CHARS = 1024
s = create_string_buffer(N_OF_CHARS)

mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("library")
mydll.Method(50, s, 20)

print(s.value)
```

Comment: Amazing it seems to be fine :) And Can i ask you please what have i to use if i need pointer to someting else? for example int?

Comment: ahh probably `i = c_int()` is pointer to int :) that was easy

Comment: `i = c_int()` creates an integer. If you want to pass it by reference (as a pointer to int) you can use `byref(i)`.